# Difference between apk (.apk) and app bundle (.aab)

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle

Recently Google brought up a new feature `app bundle` which is a pretty similar concept to APK except its flexibility and architectural differences.

I have read out lots of blog/articles to understand how app bundle works in devices in comparison with APK file.

What is the actual internal working process of app bundle and how it works on Android devices starting from Google Play Store?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/

Comment: saw that. But from google play to android device working process is pretty unclear.

Comment: WHat is unclear about it? google takes your apk with your signature your provide them splits it up into separate apk's for different resolutions and such and when a device downloads it, google play provides the correct apk for that device type

Comment: An aab is still sort of an apk, they just throw out irrelevant pieces depending on the device that downloads the app in the end. The process happening between you uploading an aab and a device downloading an apk is essentially [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/test) running on google's play store servers.

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-dynamic-app/index.html#0

Answer (score 242, accepted):

App Bundles are a publishing format, whereas APK (Android application PacKage) is the packaging format which eventually will be installed on device.

App Bundles use [bundletool](https://github.com/google/bundletool) to create a set of APK. (.apks)
This can be extracted and the base and configuration splits as well as potential dynamic feature modules can be deployed to a device.

The dependencies can look something like this:
[image: Bundletool modules]

The contents of an App Bundle look kind of like this:
[image: Bundletool contents]

More information on App Bundles is [available here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle).

Comment: I have uploaded `.apk` file on store now I want to upload `.aab` will it matter ?

Comment: As long as they have increasing version codes you won't face any problems.

Comment: I have the same question as @Sagar, Do I need to change anything to update an aab file. Earlier, I used to upload an APK to update the app.

Comment: The upload and publication flow for both is identical.

Answer (score 113):

**App bundles** are publishing format, whereas **APK** (Android application Package) is the packaging format which eventually will be installed on device.

Google uses **app bundle** to generate and serve **optimized** APKs for each user’s device configuration, so they download only the code and resources they need to run your app. Therefore, users can get **smaller** and more **optimized** downloads.

[image]

Comment: So Google haven't decided to deprecate APK format and I will be able to install any APK in future Android verstion, right? I have an open source android APP written by myself and I haven't released It on Play Store.

Comment: You better start using AAB, Googla said: Google Play will start requiring new apps to be published with the Android App Bundle starting August 2021

Comment: My app is open source software without payments. I do not want to distribute my app with Google play store because I don't want to pay Google. The price isn't that big, but why should I? I asked about Google's plans about dropping APK format support.

Comment: this is simple and nice explanation. :)

Answer (score 32):

Following are benefits of Android App Bundle over APK on PlayStore:

1. Smaller Download Size
2. On Demand App features
3. Asset-only modules