# Gradlew bundleRelease doesnt generate release apk in react-native

Tags: react-native

*I try to get apk of app. I did it before  well. However, I tried to use get apk of other app today but  it doesnt give me release apk. why ?*

*I followed [these steps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android)*

*Normally, it takes 2-3 minutes but now it lasts just 3 sec and doesnt generate apk*

*it says this :*

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 6.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
> individual deprecation warnings. See
> https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Comment: I have the same problem and looking for the answer . Maybe somebody know how to lock all the versions that if there is some update it will be not installed. Come back to the project after 2 weeks and nothing works .

Comment: It seems there is a new way to upload app on Play store. There is a migration section on official doc https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#migrating-old-android-react-native-apps-to-use-app-signing-by-google-play I have the same issue and will try to migrate soon to check if it works.

Comment: Or maybe you should use `./gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: @hakan Have you able to generate the APK with "./gradlew bundleRelease" command that is there in the React Native document.? I am able to generate .aab file but not the APK file. Can you please tell me how we need to generate the APK file with that command.

Note: I was able to generate release APK with "./gradlew assembleRelease" but somehow its not working in android real device or emulator.

Please help me on this I stuck over here.

Comment: Hi @Amar  watch this video: [How to generate APK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cws_eQ5LQUk)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I had the same problem. Following command worked for me:

After the `./gradlew bundleRelease` command we get a *.aab* version of our app. To get APK, you should run the app with release version on any device with the below command.

- Make sure you have connected an android device
- For the production ready app, firstly you have to remove the previous app from the device

Run this command in `your-project/`:

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

Then APK can be found in `android/app/build/outputs/apk/release`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! This solution is what I needed. This solution will directly install your APK to your device.

Comment: Yeah worked for me too. Still seatching for why ? :D

Comment: This worked for me, but first I had to delete the previously generated .apk file, and uninstall it from my device.

Comment: Yeah, for the production ready app, firstly you have to remove the previous app on the device 

Answer (score 46):

the short answer uses `gradlew assembleRelease` instead.

not short answer :) The command you are using `gradlew bundleRelease` builds an android App bundle. read this:
[Difference between apk (.apk) and app bundle (.aab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059339/difference-between-apk-apk-and-app-bundle-aab)
and this:
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
AAB file is new and not all stores support it.

Answer (score 17):

Use `gradlew bundleRelease` to generate an app bundle (.aab file) and `gradlew assembleRelease` to generate an apk (.apk file). To install a release on your emulator, use `react-native run-android --variant=release`. I hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

Cutting the long story short the command `gradlew bundleRelease` is used to generate an .aab file where as the command `gradlew assembleRelease` is used to generate .apk file so use the command accordingly

Comment: Quick and on the point answer. thanks

Answer (score 4):

I made a file that called `build.sh`.
When i want to release a new version of android in ReactNative, just type and press `sh ./build.sh` in terminal.

My shell script in `build.sh` file:

```
npx jetify && cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease && ./gradlew bundleRelease && cd ..
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply open the **Build Variants** window on the bottom left hand corner of Android Studio and choose *release* as the current variant:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following should solve your issue:

Open Android Studio and select "build bundle(s)" from Build/Build Bundle(s)/Apk(s)

[image: Refer this image]

Then, open your console and run

```
cd android &&  ./gradlew bundleRelease
```

from your project's root. You may encounter an error such as

> Cannot add task 'wrapper' as a task with that name already exists., because overriding built-in tasks are deprecated in 4.8 and produces an error.

To prevent it, please update your `android/build.gradle`, as follows:

FROM:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'    
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

TO:

```
wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Lastly, don't forget to convert your `.aab` file to `.apk` through `bundletool` in order to test locally your app (exactly as an APK file)

Answer (score 0):

step - 1) ./gradlew bundleRelease

step - 2) react-native run-android --variant=release

Make sure you have connected an android device
For the production-ready app, firstly you have to remove the previous app from the device

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

./gradlew app:bundleRelease Will fix your problem for sure.