# Which is a good practice to upload an APK on playstore? Is it better to use a Signed APK or Bundle

Tags: android, apk, bundle, signed-apk

Currently I have 2 apks (64bit and 32bit) to upload on playstore. So I would like to know which method is better for doing upload-APK or Bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use App Bundle if you are uploading your apk to the playstore.

## 1. Size:

People have managed to reduce almost 50% of the app size even after the heavy optimization. You don't have to suffer the app quality also while doing so. Plus, google has now started to give you a warning if you don't upload the app bundle and use the `apk` instead.

## 2. Dynamic Functionality

App Bundle is actually a bundle that consists a set of your `APKs`. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059339/difference-between-apk-apk-and-app-bundle-aab)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :) Now I understood.

Comment: Glad i could help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Android App bundle enables two feature in android app development.
1. Dynamic delivery system
2. Modular App development

There are many more addition benefits of .aab. Please refer this discussion for a better understanding -

https://medium.com/mindorks/android-app-bundle-aab-98de6dad8ba8

Comment: It helped me a lot :) Thank you