# Why did user data becomes large after moving to android bundle?

Tags: android, google-play

due to the 64-bit support; I've switched from uploading APK to uploading bundle to Play Store. However I noticed that although the APK have been getting smaller, the "User data" size (view from phone's settings) have now becomes much larger. Below are an example for my app:

**Using APK**:

- Total: 105MB
- App size: 102MB
- User data: 504KB
- Cache: 3.21MB

**Using Bundle**:

- Total: 45.34MB
- App size: 5.02MB
- User data: 39.14MB
- Cache: 1.18MB

Although I can understand why the App size is much smaller (Play Store only downloads what is needed by the device), I'm curious what exactly causes the User data to becomes this large? Did Play Store treats the components needed to be downloaded as User data?

*Not sure if it's related, but the app was built by using React Native.

Comment: This calculate is right after user install application or user use it for longer time?

Comment: @PhanVanLinh The APK values are taken after using it for a while, but the bundle values are taken after installing and opening the app once.

Comment: Also notice the cache diff.. I think some things are moved between cache, user data and app size like login and user activity using bundle.. I was wondering the same because my app comes around 15mb while uploading and after install app size goes to 50 some odd MB in one device and 27MB in another..

Comment: @rabbit87 Hi, did you manage to get an answer for this? this is still happening on the latest react native version

Comment: @rabbit87 did the proposed answer help?

Answer (score 2):

I had a little reading about APK. vs. Bundles and based on what I understood, APKs have all of the app's files and code inside while Bundles have all the DATA and basic settings needed to run your app...

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53396721/16409598) shall answer your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Some of app features or library that you are using will be installed in User Data when the app needs them only.

You can use this feature manually by [Customize Feature Delivery.](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery#customize_delivery)