# Is it possible to build an App Bundle using an already release signed APK, in Android Studio? I want to migrate apk to app bundle for play store

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using the Unity Engine to build apk. Then I use that APK on Enhance to integrate the SDK's. AAB format is not accepted, therefore I need to build APK rather than AAB directly from Unity. Then I want that integrated APK to be migrated to App Bundle to upload to PlayStore.

I had tried finding it on documentation provided by Google for App bundle development, but nothing found. If you can help me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is it possible to build an App Bundle using an already release signed APK*

> **NO.** You can convert an AAB to APK but not vice versa. Check this for [Generate Apk file from aab file (android app bundle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040047/generate-apk-file-from-aab-file-android-app-bundle)

*I want to migrate apk to app bundle for play store*

> You can migrate anytime and upload an apk or app bundle for any releases. Android (Google) doesn't restrict and accepts either of it in the Play Store.
>
> However, you need to make sure you increment your `versionCode` to make sure everyone gets the update.

Also I **recommend** you to refer,

- https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool
- [Difference between apk (.apk) and app bundle (.aab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059339/difference-between-apk-apk-and-app-bundle-aab)