# Android Release Migrate from APK to App Bundle

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-app-bundle, app-bundle

I have existing android app with APK release on playstore and I know there are already some of the same answers about migrate to **App Bundle Format** just like this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57864903/3073003

but I have a problem,
where the release with the App bundle has been rolled out for 2 days ago, but in the playstore the version isn't up

**# Play console**
[image]
[image: on play console]

**# Play store**
[image: on play store]

is this really the case? or is there an issue with that?
please let me know it, I am very confused about this.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: With the covid situation, apps are slower to be reviewed, give it a another day or so.

Comment: Is your problem fixed now?

Comment: nope :(, and there is no answer from developer support, they just said they prioritizing app published, commissioned, or authorized by official government entities and public health organizations or anything relating to covid-19

Answer (score 0):

On some OS, it takes time to update the latest app version, my suggestion would to be to check on different devices, oneplus, mi, moto, pixel and samsung. If none of the devices have update then it would be a issue, else within a week it would be updated.

Comment: I've checked in few device like xiaomi, infinix, samsung, realme, n motorola, but there is no update..