# Difference between APK extension(OBB file) and app Bundle

Tags: android

What is the difference between `apk extension`(OBB files) and `app bundle`?

Is `app bundle` is replacement for `apk extension`? and can be safely replaced? in terms of:

- files format
- file size
- folders structure
- Android api level

I am using OBB files long time, but there are some issues with jobb tool and seems like no one want to fix them since 2013:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36968595

So my question is more about safe replacement of OBB files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between apk (.apk) and app bundle (.aab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059339/difference-between-apk-apk-and-app-bundle-aab)

Comment: @schrodingers_cat16 i think it different questions, i am asking about APK extension(OBB files)

Comment: i see. Its clearer now that you've edited the post. Maybe take a look at the answer in the link. It'll tell you more about app bundles. Basically .obb format is used for keeping additional assets not in the .apk. Developers can use any format they like to do this, but its .obb is particularly popular because of the JOBB tool that comes with the android sdk i think.

Answer (score 3):

**App Bundle** is a new format for your artifacts.

> An Android App Bundle is a new upload format that includes all your app’s compiled code and resources, but defers APK generation and signing to Google Play.

Broadly speaking app bundle's core feature is dynamic delivery. Meaning deliver what the user needs. The basic feature of app bundle is to exclude things from the deliverable artifact. The APK contains useless, for some users, resources such as strings or drawables. App Bundle delivery will mean that the user gets only what they need.

For example, if the device needs hdpi drawables and English copy then all the rest resources are not bundled in the deliverable artifact.

What can replace APK expansion files is dynamic features which are enabled by App Bundle. Basically means serve a dynamic feature module on demand.

Read more about Dynamic Features [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery).

Answer (score 1):

**App Bundle** will build the APK that is targeted for a specific device and its configuration, this means that the APKs delivered will generally of a smaller size. This will really depend on your application, as the main savings will be from density / locale specific resources and any other unused code.

Read more explanation at https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-the-android-app-bundle-ca16846fa3d7