# Nativescript 7.0 blank Hello World app size 30MB

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-vue

I created a new NS project with `ns create` and selected the `plain JS template`, after that I simply ran `ns run android` and the size of the APK I got is almost 30MB (29.7MB)

This is what Android Studio profiling shows (*82.8%* size is taken by `lib`):

[image]

An excerpt from this article on [NativeScript's website](https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-android-application-package-size-revealed/) says,

> ...blank NativeScript projects for Android are ~12MB by default because they include three copies of the NativeScript runtime built for different Android CPU architectures.

But that's clearly not the case here. I tried creating a new project with hello world `vue template`, the apk size was again around *30MB*. Isn't that TOO MUCH? How can I get it to atleast 12MBs (as mentioned on the official website) ?

I tried ABI split mechanism as well, but even for a SEPARATE x86 build, size comes around *12.2MB*. How to reduce the APK SIZE for a blank project?

Comment: Did you tried release version of apk ?

Comment: Okay, so release version is giving around 24.6MB (which is still HUGE).

Answer (score 0):

This can be an **Old documentation issue** again.

```
ns build android --env.uglify
```

Will make some size fixes. But using `--aab` flag will make real difference

[Check out this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53396721/11993949)

---

### For nativescript-vue:

You can check package.json file of vue-cli-template you will see [some packages are not used but still there.](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template/blob/64e2c99cc0e6b588b34f15e0649e02b3d216cf71/template/package.json#L13)

**You don't need :**

- @vue/devtools
- nativescript-socketio
- nativescript-vue-devtools
- nativescript-toasty

https://github.com/nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template

Comment: i will try using these flags and update later. till then, can you list the packages that not used at all and can be removed safely?