# how upload app with dynamic feature to google play?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, dynamic-feature-module

APks generated in my app mode debug

[image: APks generated in my app mode debug]

It generates the apk in debug mode, in release mode it sends me an abb, but how do I get the application uploaded to the play store.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between apk (.apk) and app bundle (.aab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059339/difference-between-apk-apk-and-app-bundle-aab)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Google Play Console account (costs a one time fee of $25) -> Create App (follow all the steps)-> New Release, then upload your aab/apk in the given section, and your good to go.

Note: Google announced that all apps will be moved to the aab format, so I would recommend that you use aab instead of apk for release.