# how can i release apk again after editing code in an already release app in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have used this command
cd android
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleRelease
npx react-native run-android --variant=release

but i found apk first one not update one.

Comment: Do you want to test your code in production mode? Could you please explain your main aim to edit it?

Comment: Do you want to update .apk file after installation on user device?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build apk again to see changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. You must publish a new version. And you cannot delete any version from Google play console

Answer (score 0):

The command that you have used `./gradlew clean ./gradlew assembleRelease npx react-native run-android --variant=release` simply creates a new AAB (here you can check the [difference between an APK and an AAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059339/difference-between-apk-apk-and-app-bundle-aab)) for release on the Google Play Store.

From your question:

> but i found apk first one not update one.

It seems that the new AAB is overwriting the previous one (which is expected). So, if you want to release this new version, you must go to your Google Play Developer Console, create a new version for production, and upload the AAB you just created.